# Scroll function in EditText not working as desired

Tags: android

I have an activity that contains an EditText with a static height so that the user will have to scroll by panning in order to see the complete text when a long text is written. However, when the virtual keyboard is present, the user is not able to scroll to the upper and/or lower rows.

I have searched but could not find any solution to this issue. Any suggestions of how I can customize the XML (provided below) to let the user be able to scroll and view the whole text?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
       <!-- This is for test purpose only -->  android:maxLines="3">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: Due to design restrictions for the application the height needs to be static set and not wrap_content... Setting the maxLines to a low number might have saved me, but again, it's not appropriate because of the looks.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem too.

Fixed it by adding a property `android:isScrollContainer="true` to your `EditText`.